# launch application from ApplicationMenuItem

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I am new to blackberry and I am trying to launch my running application from active call screen via ApplicationMenuItem that I added. Menu item code below

```
public class MobExMenuItem extends ApplicationMenuItem {

    public MobExMenuItem(int order) {
        super(order);
    }

    public Object run(Object context) {
        try {
            ApplicationDescriptor descriptors[] = ApplicationManager
                    .getApplicationManager().getVisibleApplications();
            String appname = descriptors[1].getModuleName();
            ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager()
                    .launch(appname + "?admin&secure");
        } catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
            MobExLogger.e("MobExMenuItem", e.getMessage());
        }
        return context;
    }
}
```

The question is - I need that menu item opens last active screen in application, but it always opens Home screen. Is there any way to open last screen?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer just need to remove parameters and lounch the app
launch(appname);